# calculating Shannon Diversity Index error

Tags: vegan

I keep getting the below error when trying to calculate Shannon Diversity Index using R's vegan package:
Error in diversity(div.site, index = "shannon", MARGIN = 1, base = exp(1)) :
input data must be numeric

Here is my code:

```
div.site<-read.csv("POLL.DIV.SITE.csv")
diversity(div.site, index = "shannon", MARGIN = 1, base = exp(1))
fisher.alpha(x, MARGIN = 1, ...)
specnumber(div.site, groups, MARGIN = 1)
```

[image: dataset]

Comment: I think the first idea is to supply numeric data. What do you get from `sum(div.site)`? If you get a number, you have numeric data and, `vegan::diversity(div.site)` does something wrong. If you do not get a number, you do something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove all columns that are not numerical. You do not need name and site to calculate Shannon index. Make sure the column "Count" is a numerical and not a vector.